# Use debug serial pins to connect with a serial device on beaglebone rev c

Tags: serial-port, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I Have a RF module that communicate using serial port using RS232. It works in a normal computer.

I noticed that beaglebone has a serial debug slot and I tried to connect my device to it but, I can't send or receive messages using the serial debug slot.

If I connect the beaglebone to usb converting to RS232, I'll be able to communicate with my RF module. And I tested to connect by SSH using the serial slot and worked.

But I would like to use USB for another purpose. Is there a serial pins to be compatible with RS232?

Comment: *"serial debug slot"* -- Not every connector is a "slot".  Only connectors that are long and narrow, e.g. (board) edge connectors, are called slots.  Serial ports (e.g. DB-9 or DE-9 connectors) do not look like a "slot" to me.  Misuse of jargon can mark you as a newbie.

Comment: Get an oscilloscope or study the documentation of both ends of the serial link to determine the transmit-to-receive connections (i.e. the pin-out at each connector).

Comment: Sorry about I already studied, the connections are right. I think, there is some SO setting.

Comment: I referred slot because BeagleBone has six pins on-board serial ports.